# Angle brackets --portuguese keyboard not able to find

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am using portuguese laptop and keyboard. I am unable to find the keys for typing angle brackets through keyboard.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these should work, but without more information, specific answer is not possible.

1. Use [Character Map (Windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map_(Windows)).
2. Use [Compose Key (Linux).](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en)
3. Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> (Windows) while entering the four-digit key codes (0060 or 0062).
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> (Linux) and then enter the four-digit key codes (0060 or 0062).
5. Use a third-party tool, such as [KeyTweak](https://keytweak.en.softonic.com/), [ShaprKeys](https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/), or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/keytweak/) to map those ASCII codes (0x3C or 0x3E) to another key.